# Eclipse: SDK Manager not installing SDK Platform tools?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am trying to Install the `SDK Platform tools` within my `SDK manager` in `Eclipse.`

The versions of Eclipse, SDK and ADT I am using are:

```
Eclipse Luna

SDK version 21.0.0 

ADT version 21.0.0
```

Note: I am **purposely** using older versions as they are compatible with a `plugin` tool I wish to use.

When I open `SDK manager` and try to install the SDK platform tools, the Manager states that they have been installed but this is **not** the case. If SDK manager is shut and re-opened the tools have **not** been installed.

Why is this the case? How can I install them?

**Screen shot** of SDK Manager:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just switch to Android Studio.
The android bundle for eclipse is dead.
I've switched to Android Studio about 3 months ago and it's way much better.

Comment: yeah but does it support older versions of plugins etc? Why is the ADT bundle "Dead" ?

Comment: Google has decided to switch their IDE to intellij instead of eclipse. So basically the eclipse bundle won't get any new features. Android Studio works with everything you need and have with eclipse

Comment: So you think that it is the way to go for new Android Developers? Also, why are google not using Eclipse anymore? Thanks a lot

Comment: I really didn't get into the reason why they decided on this move. I've been using eclipse for java for the past 6 years and was afraid of switching it. But apparently it is much better, the whole process is much easier and soon enough all of their developer documentation would be for Android Studio. So don't postpone the inevitable ;)

Comment: Ok is it possible to start using it now? Also, will Eclipse basically become obsolete when Android Studio starts being used?

Comment: Yes. Download it from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Comment: Thanks, Sorry to keep asking but can you please outline the main advantages of using it for me? It is important as I need to make a decision quick on the IDE to use!

Comment: In the link I sent you can see "Android Studio vs. Eclipse ADT Comparison". But in anycase, I think the fact that google has decided to use Intellij instead of eclipse should be a good enough reason

Answer (score 0):

try to delete what's under **Extras**.

CLOSE, RE-OPEN the manager and then try to install the platform tools again.